# knockoutjs: multiple valueUpdates and choose which update happend

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an input field with a value binding. The binding references a writable computed observable.

The intended behavior is:

- a user types some letters: The writable computed should recognize the user is still typing
- a user finishes typing: The writable should save the value

However, I only can choose `updateValue: 'input'` or `updateValue: 'keydown'`, but not both. In the JavaScript code, the writable computed is not able to check which event occurred.

I need this behavior for this reason: if the user is just typing I want to fill an auto-suggestion box and want to bold the already typed letters. For this I need the `keydown` event. But if the user finishes typing (losing focus) I want to do some verification and then save the entered value.
If I use `input` the verification is working but the auto-suggestion feature is broken. If I use `keydown` the user isn't able to type something, because the verification always fails and the user cannot finish typing.

Comment: Some simple jsfiddle would be nice, so we had something to play with

Comment: already answerd. But thx, next time i will provide a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have computed named `self.inputValue` which references to the input field.

You can apply rateLimit extender on perticular computed..

e.g.

```
self.inputValue = ko.computed(function(){
    //perform the required logic
}).extend({ rateLimit: { method: "notifyWhenChangesStop", timeout: 400 } });;
```

where `timeout` is in miliseconds. It will hold the updation or notification of value for 400 miliseconds.

This should solve your problem. A small JSFiddle I've made for you : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/x8jmcpLh/

**rateLimit was introduced in KO 3.1.0, if you are using old library then use [throttle](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) instead.**

Comment: thx for your solution. But...my requirements have changed. I allow invalid inputs. If the user saves the model to the backend i'll validate the input. So i'm using the ´keydown´ listener which is updating my auto-suggestion box and validation happens on save. I choose your answer as solution, because it anwsers the question.